# How to access flash site that is rejecting my plugin (64-bit)?

Tags: chrome, firefox, adobe-flash

I am trying to buy tickets on stubhub.com but the site is telling that I need to install the flash plugin. I already have a 64-bit flash plugin (Adobe) installed on my Fedora 14 64-bit system. youtube and all other flash content I have tried has worked fine. Just stubhub.com is a problem. I have tried both Firefox 4 and Chrome 9 with no success, however the page loaded fine on Chrome in Windows 7. So I am not sure if it is my plugin or browser, or both that is to blame. I was thinking about trying a 32bit plugin but I am not sure if that would work.

There was a thread at linuxquestions.org, but no solutions:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/flash-player-problem-sometimes-857110/

Is there anyway that I can diagnose and bypass the plugin check on stubhub.com?

I am sorry if this isn't a very clear question, but I never thought Linux would come between me and a pair of Yankees tickets.

**UPDATE** Using both a wrapped 32-bit flash plugin and leigh123linux's 64-bit Fedora RPM plugin worked fine.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use your Windows installation for this? Otherwise, you might consider using a virtual machine eg Virtualbox, which apparently boots Windows. Site-specific Flash problems are usually hard to diagnose.

Comment: I used Windows at work, at the moment I don't have a Windows install at home so I am 'stuck' with Linux. I figured that would be the case, but am still holding onto hope that this can be resolved.

Comment: Random thought. Try using Chromium rather than Chrome, if available on Fedora. The flash plugin tends to work better with Chromium in my experience. Though if flash in Chrome works for with most sites, it is probably not going to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tried looking at the [link](http://www.stubhub.com/philadelphia-phillies-tickets/phillies-vs-mets-4-6-2011-1007979/) in the thread you pointed to (BTW next time please include such links so that it's easier for others to look at your problem) and everything is working fine. Of course I haven't actually bought the tickets but I've got to the screen where the site asks me to pay so I guess that's good enough. I'm using Chromium.

There is a difference that may make things work for you: I use the 32-bit plugin together with nspluginwrapper. There are instructions for [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Flash#32_bit_wrapped_version).

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'll try this at work this morning. Need to get these tickets while the Yanks bats are still hot! They should be for a while though...;)

Comment: Well, that did it! I removed my 64-bit plugin and followed the instructions on the linked page. However, I do dislike having to work around my system like this. I just wish Adobe would get with the program with Linux flash. At least now I can enjoy the Yankees next Friday.